# RMarkdown user definded functions give error

Tags: r

I'm working in trying to solve why when I define a function in a RMarkdown I end up with an error when trying to call it from any other part of the document.

```
{r}
# FUNCIONES AUXILIARES 


espectro.imager <- function(fft.arg){
  # cimg
  Mod <- sqrt(fft.arg$real^(2)+fft.arg$imag^(2))
  return(Mod)
}

argumento.imager <- function(fft.arg){
  # cimg
  Arg.array <- atan2(as.matrix(fft.arg$real,nrow=1),as.matrix(fft.arg$imag,nrow=1))
  Arg <- as.cimg(matrix(Arg.array,ncol=dim(fft.arg$real)[2]))
  return(Arg)
}


# Pasamos la imagen al dominio de las frecuencias, vamos a modificar la imagen original fmn(-1)^(m+n)
Centra.frec  <- function(M){
  M.aux <- M
  rows <- dim(M)[1]    
cols <- dim(M)[2]   
for (i in 1:rows){
  for (j in 1:cols) {
    M.aux[i,j] <- M[i,j]*(-1)^(i+j-2)
    # Trasparencia 21
  }
}
return(M.aux)
}


###############################################
#
# Filtro Butterword
#
###############################################

FButterword <- function (rows, cols,orden,radio){
  FB <- matrix(rep(0,rows*cols),rows,cols) #Inicializamos
  #n Orden del Filtro
  #D0 Frecuencia Umbral
  for (i in 1:rows){
    for (j in 1:cols) {
      r <- sqrt((i-rows/2)^2+(j-cols/2)^2)
      FB[i,j] <- 1/(1+(r/radio)^(2*orden))
    }
  } 
  return(FB)
}

**fimg <- Centra.frec(img_raw)**
```

When calling the function with an image I have previously loaded the following error occurs:

Error in NextMethod() : objeto 'i' no encontrado
7.
NextMethod()
6.
`[.cimg`(structure(c(0.419607843137255, 0.466666666666667, 0.737254901960784, 0.933333333333333, 0.63921568627451, 0.411764705882353, 0.658823529411765, 0.874509803921569, 0.623529411764706, 0.23921568627451, 0.352941176470588, 0.462745098039216, 0.337254901960784, 0.392156862745098, 0.466666666666667, ...
5.
structure(c(0.419607843137255, 0.466666666666667, 0.737254901960784, 0.933333333333333, 0.63921568627451, 0.411764705882353, 0.658823529411765, 0.874509803921569, 0.623529411764706, 0.23921568627451, 0.352941176470588, 0.462745098039216, 0.337254901960784, 0.392156862745098, 0.466666666666667, ...
4.
do.call("[", c(list(x), c(ar)))
3.
`[.cimg`(M, i, j)
2.
M[i, j]
1.
Centra.frec(img_raw)

If you find any clue about why I can't use these user defined functions I would be thankful.